# SwiftUI: strange behavior ScrollView

Tags: scrollview, swiftui

When using vertical and horizontal scrolling, I cannot see the upper left corner in Image.
But at the same time there is some space after the lower right corner.
How to fix it ?

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:  500.0, height: 500.0)
            }.frame(width:  300.0, height: 300.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem here. According to my tests, it is fixed in Xcode 12, which means either SwiftUI 2.0 and/or iOS 14 fixes it. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You just add an offset for the content of scrolling view

```
   var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
              Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                  .resizable()
                .frame(width:  500.0, height: 500.0).offset(x: 100, y: 100)
          }.frame(width:  300.0, height: 300.0)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Offset value  depended from resolution and orientation

Comment: That's because both frames are arbitrary. you can use geometryReader to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
            VStack {
                Spacer(minLength: 200)
                HStack {
                    Spacer(minLength: 200)
                    Image(systemName: "keyboard")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks better, but still strange